# Python string.Template: Replace field containing spaces

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

Using Python's string.Template class - how might I utilize the ${} for fields in a dictionary that contain spaces?

E.g.

```
t = string.Template("hello ${some field}")
d = { "some field": "world" }
print( t.substitute(d) ) # Returns "invalid placeholder in string"
```

---

**Edit**: Here's the closest I could get, with the caveat being that all variables need to be wrapped in a brackets (otherwise all space separated words would be matched).

```
class MyTemplate(string.Template):
   delimiter = '$'
   idpattern = '[_a-z][\s_a-z0-9]*'

t = MyTemplate("${foo foo} world ${bar}")
s = t.substitute({ "foo foo": "hello", "bar": "goodbye" })
# hello world goodbye
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this might be helpful to somebody else. In python 3 you can use `format_map`:

```
t = "hello {some field}"
d = { "some field": "world" }
print( t.format_map(d) )

# hello world
```

Comment: Ah, this looks nice - is it Python 3 only? I probably should have mentioned the necessity for Python 2.7x support

Comment: You can use simply the `.format` method of `str`: `print('hello {some field}'.format(**d))`

Answer (score 0):

From Doc it says that we could use Template option

https://docs.python.org/dev/library/string.html#template-strings

```
import string

class MyTemplate(string.Template):
    delimiter = '%'
    idpattern = '[a-z]+ [a-z]+'

t = MyTemplate('%% %with_underscore %notunderscored')
d = { 'with_underscore':'replaced', 
      'notunderscored':'not replaced',
      }

print t.safe_substitute(d)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by this - what output are you expecting to get? I just ran this code and got "% %with_underscore not replaced"

Comment: This is a pretty close approximation to what I want, as long as all variables are enclosed in {} (if you update your answer with this or something similar, I'll mark it as correct): idpattern = '[_a-z][_\sa-z0-9]*'